# Quick view code or script

Tags: jquery, html, css

### Goal

I would like to display a bar of text overlaying an image, vertically-centered and hard aligned to the left and right edges, when someone hovers on the containing link. I'm not sure what is the easiest and best way to do it.

This is the effect I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Vertically-centered bar of text reading "quick view" overlaying a product image.]

### Code

Here is the HTML I'm working with:

```
<ul class="products">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/product-image.jpg" class="photo" /></a>

        <div class="text_holder">
            <h3>Product name</h3>  
            <p class="description">Short description below product name</p>
            <p class="price">$29.99<em>Was: $59.99</em></p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### What I've tried already

I'm open to both pure CSS and jQuery solutions. I have already tried several tooltip scripts, but none of them worked well enough: some didn't allow the tooltip to be used as a link, while others were not visible within the product image area. I also tried a similar approach to what Ryan Silva is suggesting below but with no luck.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do, and what have you tried so far? This is a place to get help with problems you ecounter, not for us to write the code for you.

Comment: Ole, sorry if I wasn't clear enough with what I'm trying to accomplish. As for what I tried - well I tried several tooltip scripts but none of them worked well enough (some couldn't serve as a link, some were not visible over complete area of the product image). I also tried similar solution to what ryansilva is suggesting below but without luck. I thought someone has already solved this common issue and can provide link or suggestion.

Comment: To clarify: if you hover over the image, you want to show an overlay including the text "quick view," and you should be able to click anywhere to open the quick view? And it is only this hover effect that you want to implement?

Comment: @ Jordan Gray - exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yoooudLt/)**

**HTML**

```
<ul class="products">
<li>
        <div class="outer"><img src="http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2012/282/c/7/emma_watson_portrait_by_prod44-d5hcxul.jpg" class="photo" />
        <div class="quick">
            <p>Quick View</p>
         </div>
        </div>

        <div class="text_holder">
            <h3>Product name</h3>  
            <p class="description">Short description below product name</p>
            <p class="price">$29.99<em>Was: $59.99</em></p>
        </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
     li{
   list-style:none; 
    text-align:center;    
}img{
    width:100%;
    padding:5%;
     border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

.outer{ 
    position: relative;
    width:300px;

}
.quick{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;    
    margin-top:-75%;
    padding:0 5%;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    display:none;
}

.outer:hover img{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.outer:hover .quick{
     display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to set up a CSS rule which adds the hover image to the :[before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudoelement of the link when you hover over it. If you made the link `position: relative` you could add the pseudoelement with the same dimensions as the image behind it, and `position:absolute` so that it floats on top.

Comment: Will try, sounds like way to go and skip jquery. Thanks for being precise!